# upi payment getting error in razorpay android integration

Tags: android, razorpay

I am working on the android studio when I am trying payment gateway integration using Razorpay. when I am using the card payment method it is working fine but whenever using the UPI payment method it gives the following error.

```
com.example.navdrawerdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.navdrawerdemo, PID: 31569
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.navdrawerdemo/com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5141)
        at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: null
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1459)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1642)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:715)
        at com.razorpay.CheckoutPresenterImpl.cleanUpOnDestroy(CheckoutPresenterImpl.java:705)
        at com.razorpay.PluginOtpElfCheckoutPresenterImpl.cleanUpOnDestroy(PluginOtpElfCheckoutPresenterImpl.java:17)
        at com.razorpay.a_$P$.onDestroy(BaseCheckoutActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8245)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5141) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

Comment: Is your issue fixed? 
Did you follow this 
https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/faqs/

mentioned in
https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/

Let me know if this fixed your issues.
I have done the above thing but I am still facing this issue of upi payments failing and cards working thing. the Razorpay checkout screen opens an UPI wallet like phonepe and doesn't come back to the main app/checkout screen after payment is successful.